# Keep track of the state of event in multiprocessing by writing to file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am working on a task that requires multiprocessing in python and I need to keep track of the state by writing already processed document IDs to a file (a single file shared among processes).

I have implemented a simple version using the code snippet below. In the code, I have some Ids stored in a variable called `question`, the shared file `f` and in the main method, I split the `question` into possible chunks that can be processed parallel.

Is this the right way to do such?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Queue

def reader(val):
  pqueue.put(val)

def writer():
  a = pqueue.get()
  f = open("num.txt",'a')
  f.write(str(a))
  f.write("\n")
  f.close()
  

def main():
  
  global question
  global pqueue
  pqueue = Queue() # writer() writes to pqueue from _this_ process

  
  processes = []
  question = [16,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15]
  cores=5
  loww=0
  chunksize = int((len(question)-loww)/cores)
  splits = []
  for i in range(cores):
    splits.append(loww+1+((i)*chunksize))
  splits.append(len(question)+1)
  print(splits)
  args = []
  for i in range(cores):
    a=[]
    arguments = (i, splits[i], splits[i+1])
    a.append(arguments)
    args.append(a)
  print(args)
  p = Pool(cores)
  p.map(call_process, args)
  p.close()
  p.join

def call_process(args):
  lower=args[0][1]
  upper=args[0][2]
  for x in range(lower,upper):
    a = question[x-1]
    try:
      pass
    except:
      continue
    #write item to file
    print(f,'a = ',a)
    reader(a)
    writer()
    


main()
```

Note: the code seems not to be working.

Comment: are you still using python 2.7, `print()` is invalid in 2.7 unless you import from `__futures__`

Comment: I'm using python3.6

Comment: then why tag with python2.7

Comment: I've removed the tag

Answer (score 1):

Sooner or later you'll have a process trying to open a file while another process was in the process of writing to the file, and things will break.

Rather, my strategy would be:

1. Start a process, call this "chronicler", that monitors a Queue for incoming bits & pieces, and everytime something comes in, write to the file.
2. Start the workers. Everytime a worker is done, push some bits & pieces into the aforementioned Queue. Then continue with the next task (thus handing off all file-open-write-and-close process to the "chronicler")
3. Have all of them monitor an Event called "stop_and_drop_dead". The main process can set() this Event and the child processes, upon seeing the Event is set, end themselves gracefully.

Comment: Hi @pepoluan, I made some changes to the snippet in the question. Is it very close to the explanation you gave?

Comment: @JesujobaALABI nope, not even close. Read my steps again. Pay attention to every single word I've typed in the steps.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand (3)

Comment: @JesujobaALABI (3) is optional, just a way to provide graceful shutdown of the child processes. The gist of the solution is (1) and (2).